# GlassFish : How the server came to know when changes are made to autodeploy folder

Tags: glassfish, autodeploy

I am new to EJB. Recently I was testing a demo EAR file over GlassFish.

For EAR deployment I added that EAR file to GlassFish's ".autodeploy" directory.

And server started deployment. Here my question is that How the server come to know that
   we have added a new EAR file to autodeploy directory ?

Thanks,
Gunjan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GLassFish server, there is a polling time out option. You can see that in admin console->server tab.

You can change the time out option over there. so for every specified interval it looks up for the changes by comparing timestamp. If deploys the content if it found the change.

Regards,
Gunjan.